# nest client Bypass ssl Certificate error in .netcore application

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

```
var uris = new[]
                {
                    new Uri("https://10.8.173.179:9200"),
                };

                var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(uris);
                var settings = new ConnectionConfiguration(connectionPool);
                settings.BasicAuthentication("elastic", "password");
                var lowlevelClient = new ElasticLowLevelClient(settings);
                var health = lowlevelClient.Cluster.Health<StringResponse>();
```

Getting below : 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [working with certificates documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/working-with-certificates.html).

If you're using a self signed cert, you can use either the following on `ConnectionSettings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(...)`

1. `CertificateValidations.AllowAll;` to allow all certificates
2. `CertificateValidations.AuthorityIsRoot(cert)` and pass it the Certificate Authority (CA) public key to validate that the certificate the server presents is generated with the CA
3. `CertificateValidations.AuthorityPartOfChain(cert)` and pass it the certificate.

Comment: How to avoid this error : :"security","suppressed":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"current license is non-compliant for [security]","license.expired.feature":"security"}]},"status":403}

Comment: Please open a new question with as much detail needed to describe the problem.

Comment: @RussCam - Could you share how to complete this .ConnectionSettings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(...)?
I am trying like below but seems something wrong with signature
  .ServerCertificateValidationCallback(new object(), new X509Certificate(), X509Chain.Create(), SslPolicyErrors.None, true);

Comment: @FShah Is there a reason not to use one of the static methods on `CertificateValidations`?

Comment: @RussCam - There is no CertificatesValidations.AllowAll for ConnectionSettings. 
Here is my code snippet where I am  trying to use cServerCertificateValidationCallback 

`Nest.ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(fqdn))
                .DefaultIndex(this.DefaultIndex)
                .EnableDebugMode()
                .ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object(), new X509Certificate(), X509Chain.Create(), SslPolicyErrors.None, true);`

Comment: @FShah what version are you using? `.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` takes a delegate accepting 4 parameters, and returns a `bool` value. Take a look at the tests from which the docs are generated, for example: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/4c06cd6a39bc0e911f464b5a00725dd859a5216d/tests/Tests/ClientConcepts/Certificates/WorkingWithCertificates.doc.cs#L85-L90

Comment: @RussCam - using .Net core 2.2 and Nest Client 7.0.1

Comment: @FShah use the `CertificateValidations` class which exists in Elasticsearch.Net in 7.0.1: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/7.0.1/src/Elasticsearch.Net/Connection/CertificateValidations.cs